# Python funcion scope

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, python-3.7

Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

```
def List_Popped(L):
    L.pop(0)
    return L

Li = [x for x in range(10)]
print(Li)

LiPopped = List_Popped(Li)

print(Li)
print(LiPopped)
```

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

I'm having trouble understanding why popping a list value inside the List_Poped function affects the list outside of it. I tried Li.copy() outside and inside List_Poped and Li is aways affected.

I want to pop the list value inside List_Poped and have LiPopped as a result without affecting Li, so I can pass the original Li to other functions. How can I do that?

Comment: Lists are mutable objects. You passed the list to your function and your function then mutated that mutable object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good answer: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference).

For your example, if you pass `Li.copy()` to the function, it should not modify it. or if you do `L.copy().pop(0)` inside the function.

```py
def List_Popped(L):
    L.pop(0)
    return L

Li = [x for x in range(10)]
print(Li)

LiPopped = List_Popped(Li.copy())

print(Li)
print(LiPopped)
```

gives

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother whats inside whats outside. Just track which variable refers which data. Here you provided `Li` as input which was modified in the function. To prevent it, you may pass a copy of `Li`:

```
>>> List_Popped(Li.copy())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> Li
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```